# Rails ActiveRecord checkout_timeout setting ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, timeout

I have the following initializer.

/config/initializers/database_connection.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect!

  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
    config = Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
    config['reaping_frequency'] = (ENV['DB_REAP_FREQ'] || 5).to_i # seconds
    config['pool']              = (ENV['DB_POOL'] || 15).to_i
    config['checkout_timeout']  = (ENV['DB_CHECKOUT_TIMEOUT'] || 25).to_i # seconds
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
  end
end
```

I still get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError - could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 6.940 seconds)
```

The increased timeout (25 seconds) is ignored and the timeout is still happening after 5 secounds.

How should i set the checkout_timeout?

Answer (score 0):

checkout_timeout is for PostgreSQL databases;
checkout is for SQLite databases;

Might this be the issue, the wrong variable name?

Comment: I'm not so sure this is true. I tried using `checkout_timeout` on my pg database, without effect. It is possible my connection error is not timeout related, however.

Answer (score -1):

idk, how to set `config.checkout_timeout` through the config object, howerever it should be possible within database.yaml and this file should also be erb parsed, allowing you to use ENV vars within, like this:

```
production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  checkout_timeout: <%= ENV['TIMEOUT'] %>
```

I'm also not aware of setting config properties by hash access. Only through attributes

```
 config.checkout_timeout  = 5
```

however it would not surprise me, that both is possible. 
And don't forget to restart the rails server and kill spring before (`spring stop`)

Comment: database.yml is not used in production. The connectionstring is from ENV['DATABASE_URL'].

Comment: This goes around the problem, but not tackling it.
Maybe its about the way the parameters are named, or if the Database in that version allows the parameter, rather than the way the configuration is given.